# Raspberry Adafruit RGB LCD Shield, how many pins are used?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I bought this product on Adafruit : https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16x2-character-lcd-plus-keypad-for-raspberry-pi/overview

I need to know which and how many pins are used on the RPi by this product because I add a potentiometer on a breadboard.

Thank you !

Comment: You will probably get more answers if you flag your question to ask a moderator to move it to the [raspberry pi stack exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) as it's not [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This product already has a built in potentiometer that is installed during assembly.

The shield takes up all of the Raspberry Pi pins, but per the [assembly instructions](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16x2-character-lcd-plus-keypad-for-raspberry-pi/overview):

> If you want plug in a Cobbler or Gertboard at the same time, check out our Stacking Header, you can fit an IDC cable over it if the Plate is assembled with this part.

you can use the tall "stacking headers" to assemble it instead of the headers that come with it and then stack other shields nad outputs on top of it.

UPDATE

after OP said they want to control color of screen with secondary additional potentiometer:

You will need to add that as totally custom and hooking into one of the GPIO pins and detect your changes to the potentiometer and respond in the python code using the `Adafruit_CharLCDPlate class' function`set_color(red, green, blue)` - see [usage page](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16x2-character-lcd-plus-keypad-for-raspberry-pi/usage)

> **set_color(red, green, blue)** - Set the color of the red, green, and blue backlight LEDs. Each color value should be a 1 for on or 0 for off. For example to set a red backlight call set_color(1,0,0) or to set a purple color call set_color(1,0,1).

Comment: Ok thank you, but I'd like to add another potentiometer to change the color of the screen actually. The potentiometer that adafruit gave is the one that manage the contrast. It seems that there is only one SCLK pin that I need for my aditionnal potentiometer. Seems like I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

I  have the same lcd and button pcb.

Along with the above answer while it comes with a ribbon cable type connection only 4 of the pins are needed to run the bored. 5v gnd and the 2 i2c ways so you can remote  the bored or use the other gpio as well

[image: pins 2, 3, 5 and 6]

I hope this helps